# Функция в скобках

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не очень силен в JavaScript поэтому хотел бы спросить вот что. Не раз сталкивался с вот таким объявлением функции в JS:

```
(function($) {

    //...
})(jQuery);
```

Для чего нужно оборачивать объявление функции в скобки и что означает (jQuery) после это функции в скобках?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/222174/javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

Здесь объявляется анонимная функция и сразу же вызывается с параметром jQuery. Это делается для того, чтобы получить вложенную область видимости (scope, скоуп) для локальных переменных, отделённую от глобальной области видимости.

Делается это для с двумя целями. Во-первых, таким образом фиксируется версия jQuery на момент исполнения кода, и если в будущем кто-то переопределит глобальную переменную jQuery (например, загрузив ещё одну версию библиотеки или вызвав noConflict) - ссылка на текущую версию jQuery останется в переменной-параметре `$`.

Во-вторых, любые локальные переменные, объявленные в такой функции через ключевое слово var, становятся невидимыми снаружи, что ведёт к уменьшению числа конфликтов с другими скриптами.

Однако, этот способ давным-давно устарел, и в современном коде использоваться не должен. Вот современный эквивалент этого кода:

```js
{
    const $ = jQuery;

    //…
}
```

Поскольку переменные, объявленные как let и const, видимы в пределах блока кода, а не функции - то и отдельную функцию заводить им не требуется.

Ещё более современный вариант предусматривает импорт скриптов при помощи ключевого слова import вместо использования глобальных переменных.

Answer (score -1):

Таким образом создается анонимная функция, а затем вызывается с параметрами jQuery

Comment: Спасибо, Капитан Очевидность!